# Некорректное отображение сайта на поддомене в браузерах Хром и Опера

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, битрикс

Здравствуйте, никак не могу разобраться в чем может быть причина. Сайт (на Битриксе) нормально отображается на всех браузерах, в том числе Хром и Опера, но у нас также есть поддомены, если выйти на страницу, расположенную на поддомене, то Хром и Опера отображают страницу некорректно, ссылаясь на неясные закэшированные файлы CSS.

Чистила историю и кэш браузеров, не помогло. В чем может быть причина и как это исправить?

Comment: Выяснить откуда берутся эти файлы

Comment: они берутся из кэша. Я не могу понять почему он их использует и почему не работает очистка кэша

Comment: А если поставить  запрет кэширования и проверить  что будет?

Comment: А я правильно понимаю по теме, что в Firefox и IE всё хорошо?

Comment: @Andrewus про IE забыла. Там тоже не очень. Все хорошо только в Firefox

Comment: А приложите скриншот из сетевой вкладки консоли разработчика хрома: там список всех загружаемых файлов.

Comment: @Andrewus он загружает CSS из кэшевых папок. При этом чистка кэша не дает результата.

Comment: Из папок /bitrix/cache, что ли?
Возможно, что их туда положили случайно при разработке, и у битрикса не хватает прав на удаление этих файлов.

Comment: @Andrewus да, из этой папки  /bitrix/cache/css/s1/es_main/, но я никак не могу понять, почему Мозилла корректно отображает, а другие браузеры нет. И как это исправить

Comment: Попробуйте для начала удалить через FTP доступ к хостинг-площадке удалить эти файлы (предварительно сделайте копию).

Comment: @Andrewus удалила, но вы не поверите, они снова тут же появились и внешний вид остался без изменений. И посмотрела, что там в этих файлах и они в целом вообще мало напоминают главный CSS сайта

Comment: Так, а в файрфоксе тоже загружаются эти стили? Из этих папок?
Посмотрите в файрфоксе и в хроме на отличающиеся элементы в панели разработчика. Одинаковые ли стили там используются?

Comment: @Andrewus посмотрела, они загружаются из тех же папок, те же стили

Comment: А приведите конкретные скриншоты -- что именно там отображается некорректно? Желательно из трех браузеров.

Comment: @Andrewus не могу разобраться, как тут чат создать, я бы вам туда отправила скрины

Comment: Скрины можно прикрепить к вопросу -- это сильно помогает.

Answer (score 0):

Я так понимаю вы используете режим многосайтовости. В этом режиме в настройках каждого сайта должен быть указан путь к корню сайта - проверьте.

Второй вариант: вы не путаете случайно, CDN и кеш? Вообще посмотрите внимательно в инструментах разработчка на URL этих файлов.

Comment: Спасибо, Александр, что откликнулись! Нет, мы не используем режим многосайтовости, это доменное имя карточки, пользовательское поле, которое заполняется менеджером при заполнении карточки. И я никак не могу понять, каким образом он собирает эту страницу и почему применяет старые css файлы